# How do I use same published array on two views and when I change the index number of any element from first view, the other does not?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm not sure the question is clear enough, but here's my problem:

I have a content view which has two views in it and a `@StateObject`. I'm passing this variable to the first and second view as `@ObservedObject`. I had to create an observable object because when i click an item in second view; the same item should be highlighted on the first view. So they should have a connection.

When I update the index number of an element by drag and drop functions in the second view, I don't want it to be updated in the first view.

This is my first question, thank you for your helps

[image: Example]

I know they're sharing the same observable objects and I know why it isn't working; but i couldn't find a solution to that :/

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var myArray = MyArray()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            FirstView(myArray: myArray)
            SecondView(myArray: myArray)
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myArray: MyArray

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First View")
            ForEach(myArray.items, id: \.id) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .onDrag {
                        let index = myArray.items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id })!
                        return NSItemProvider(object: "\(index)" as NSString)
                    }
                    .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: MyDropDelegate(myArray: myArray, currentItem: item))
            }

        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var myArray: MyArray

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second View")
            ForEach(myArray.items, id: \.id) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .onDrag {
                        let index = myArray.items.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == item.id })!
                        return NSItemProvider(object: "\(index)" as NSString)
                    }
                    .onDrop(of: [.text], delegate: MyDropDelegate(myArray: myArray, currentItem: item))
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyArray: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [MyItem(name: "Item 1"), MyItem(name: "Item 2"), MyItem(name: "Item 3")]
}
```

Comment: Is the change only local to the view or do you want `items` in `myArray` to be updated as well? There are different solutions possible here but it’s also a lot of stuff that is unclear so I don’t know which way forward is the best. What happens if new items are added to the array, can other editing be done to the items/array in the views etc

Comment: Thanks for your help! When i add an item to one of these arrays; it should be added to other one as well. Same thing should be applied when i delete an item too. Only thing i'm trying to do is; when i move the rows on the second view, the first view's elements should keep it's positions. Hope i'm clear enough

Answer (score 0):

This is actually trickier than expected. The problem is to keep ONE source of truth for both views / arrays for the selection, but differentiate on the sort order.

Basically I see two ways:

1. have ONE array of items, where each item keeps track of their position in each view (2 position vars)
2. have TWO arrays of the same identical elements (which means you have to add/delete to and from both arrays)

I went for approach 2 and made use of the new List initialiser with `editActions: .move`, which takes care of the moving of items automatically. The selection is global and passed down to both List views.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myArray = MyArray()
    @State private var selection: MyItem.ID? = nil // global selection

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            FirstView(myArray: myArray, selection: $selection)
            SecondView(myArray: myArray, selection: $selection)
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var myArray: MyArray
    @Binding var selection: MyItem.ID?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("First View")
            List ($myArray.items1, editActions: .move, selection: $selection) { $item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var myArray: MyArray
    @Binding var selection: MyItem.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second View")
            List ($myArray.items2, editActions: .move, selection: $selection) { $item in
                Text(item.name)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}


struct MyItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

class MyArray: ObservableObject {
    
    init() { // create two arrays with the same content
        let items = [
            MyItem(name: "Item 1"),
            MyItem(name: "Item 2"),
            MyItem(name: "Item 3"),
            MyItem(name: "Item 4"),
            MyItem(name: "Item 5"),
        ]
        self.items1 = items
        self.items2 = items
    }
    
    @Published var items1: [MyItem]
    @Published var items2: [MyItem]

}
```

[image]